# Javascript Regex match() not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-6

I have written a RegEx and trying to match if a input text match to it.

```
var inputtxt = document.fd.pwd;
var decimal=  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,20}$/; 

if(inputtxt.value.match(decimal))   
{   
    alert("Your Password confirms to New Password Rules.");  

}  
else  
{   
    alert("Your Password must contain atleast one each of following: \n\t 1 Uppercase alphabet \n\t 2 Lowercase alphabet \n\t 3 Digit[0-9] \n\t 4 Special Character[ie !,@,#,$ etc] \n\n It SHOULD NOT conatin any Blank spaces "); 

}
```

This code works perfectly in FF/CHrome/ IE8+ But doesn't work in IE6.

Comment: Let the IE6 die!

Comment: If you want to support IE6 you better not try anything fancy in Javascript... Can't you have a serverside validation fallback? (You'll probably need this anyway)

Comment: Probably doesn't support lookahead. Not hard to work around though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP is the only Windows platform that still supports IE6. Support for Windows XP ends in... well, have a look for yourself [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx).

Global usage of IE6 is so low (outside of China) that it can be ignored without much side effects (kind of like all those low-usage browsers most people don't even know about).

In other words, the return on investment to support IE6 is way, way, WAY too bad to even think about doing it. Just drop the support and get on with your life, you'll save both time and money.